# how to execute count query in sqlite and gets int as number of rows

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i want to retrieve counted number of rows saved in database with where clause , in SQlite, i am beginner and confused to execute this sql query

```
Select Count(*) From " + Table_Seekers + " where " + Uid + " = " + Table_Seekers
```

i want to get number of counted rows in db where incoming Uid is same in db ? so any one please help.

```
public void getReqMade(String Uid) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
    database.execSQL("Select Count(*) From " + Table_Seekers + " where " + Uid + " = " + Table_Seekers);
}
```

Comment: Show the table definition.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation for SQLiteDatabase and Cursor. These will tell you how to get the results from your query.

Answer (score 1):

If `Table_Seekers` is the name of the table and `Uid` is what you are searching then

```
Select Count(*) From Table_Seekers where Table_Seekers_field = Uid
```

Also you should name the arguments of your methods starting by a lowercase.

Comment: in sqlite ? i want to execute this in sqlite android , so which data type i store the result of this ?

Comment: this query returns an integer if that is what you are asking